# Get string from listView item?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to get the string from my listView item that I click.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

I have tried accessing it using:

```
TextView text = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

The id of the textView of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is `android:id="@android:id/text1"` but according to Eclipse `text1 cannot be resolved or is not a field`

I'm sure I'm making a mistake accessing the default android textView in the simple list item, but I'm not sure how to access it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it using `android:id="@android:**+**id/text1"` ?

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayAdapter` has `getItem(int position)`, you can rely on it to retrieve the string your a looking for. How did you get `arg1`?

Comment: arg1 is from the onItemClickListener.

Comment: the first argument is the AdapterView. you can use the AdapterView instance to call getItemAtPosition to retrieve the string

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working as the solution for me. Thanks for giving me the though user2433059

```
TextView textView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`text1` cannot be resolved because it is an Android resource and you won't be able to access it through your R variable.

You will fix your issue using:

```
TextView text = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
String itemText = text.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Yeah, I just posted that about 20 minutes ago. Thanks for backing me up on it though.

Comment: @GuyLeStack, sorry. Didn't realize that in time :/ Just make sure you accept one of the answers to "close" the topic.